# AS3 - Frame inside of a movie clip inside of a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame, movieclip

this might not make much sense but here we go. I have a movie clip (Player) and inside of that I have some frames that hold movie clips. Inside of those is an animation sequence. I wish to play certain ones on actions in AS3. So it's like this. Frame > Player(MovieClip) > Frame...Frame > playerDownBlock(MovieClip) > Frame...Frame. I wish to play the final frames in the final movieclips if I can. Is this possible?

Here is my set-up.

Layout/ Path of movieclips

[image: Img1]

[image: Img3]

[image: Img4]

I've attempted to do it by using this line.

```
Player.playerDownBlock.gotoAndPlay("playerDownBlock");
// Or
Player.gotoAndPlay("playerDownBlock");
```

None of these work and I don't know if I can even do it. Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Where is your Actionscript located?

Comment: Internal file on a frame. Right click > actions on its own frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
mc.mc2.play();
```

With "mc" being the instance name of the first outside Movie Clip and "mc2" being the instance name of the inside Movie Clip.

Comment: Would that stop it after being played once? Or would it loop?

Comment: whenever the play-head reaches this frame and comes to this code it will always play. If you want to go to a certain frame inside the movieclip inside a movieclip just write: mc.mc2.gotoAndPlay(_framenumber_);

Comment: any other questions your facing?

Comment: If I did play() could I then add some action script on to the last frame saying stop(); ?

Comment: Yep. Whenever the compiler reaches your code _play();_ or _stop();_ it will always play or stop. It sounds like your new to Flash. I would highly reccomend this book: _Learning Flash AS3_. It's a great way to learn all the basics of Flash.

Comment: Okay thanks, I believe I've got an idea. I'll look in to that book

Comment: I've still got an issue with this. When I reference that movieclip should I use an instance name or just the actual movieclip name?

Comment: you bring up a good point Kyle. Think of the Movie Clip name more like the name for the Movie Clip itself, while the instance name is for a particular instance of that Movie Clip. So in the answer I gave above the first Movie Clip's instance name is "mc", while the second Movie Clip's instance  is "mc2".

Answer (score 2):

Simple. gotoAndPlay can have a frame number or a label as a parameter. You're using a label:

```
Player.playerDownBlock.gotoAndPlay("playerDownBlock");
```

..."playerDownBlock" (just replace that last bit with the frame number):

```
Player.playerDownBlock.gotoAndPlay(25);  // or whatever
```

...or give that frame a label in the timeline and use that instead of a number.

Comment: I've set a frame label for them rather than using numbers. Would this not be the same result?

Comment: Yeah, you would get the same result. The only difference is that you're calling the frame by the label instead of the frame number

Comment: It looks like you've added the labels to "Player", but no labels for the movieClip "playerDownBlock". As it is now, you still need to use frame numbers to target the frames in "playerDownBlock". Remember, "playerDownBlock" is 'inside' "Player" in the display list.

Comment: Take the 3rd label in your above image. Using Player.gotoAndPlay("<label3>") will work right now. Try it. Put stop(); wherever you want to freeze the timeline - Flash always loops indefinitely by default. If you don't want loads of stops everywhere, try using gotoAndStop() instead.